# How do I check out a remote branch in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Just curious what the official workflow for this is. I haven't found a smooth and easy way to retrieve a specific remote branch using the VS Code UI. I can do it from the command line, of course, but it seems like there's no way to do this using the VS Code UI.

For instance, if I haven't yet checked a remote branch onto my local, it simply doesn't appear in VS Code no matter how many times I pull or fetch.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) installed, in the branches section of the Source Control tab, click the "Switch to Another Branch" button:

[image: switch branches button]

After doing that, a drop down should appear with your local and remote branches for you to switch to:

[image: drop down of branches]

Comment: ... what? is this gitlens?

Comment: @starball ah.  Looks like it.  I'll clarify that.  Gitlens adds some pretty basic features that VS Code lacks by default that I forget _just how much_ it actually adds.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout a remote branch and automatically create a local, remote-tracking branch for it by using the `Git: Checkout To...` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). It will open a menu first prompting you to select a repository if your workspace has multiple repositories, and then prompt you to select a branch to check out (remote branches will be shown in a dedicated sectio).

You can checkout a remote branch without creating a local, remote-tracking branch by using the `Git: Checkout To (Detached)...` command in the command palette. There's also a status bar indicator of the current branch that you can click to open up the same menu.

Of course, you'll need to `git fetch` to update your local repository's knowledge of what remote branches exist and what commit they point to. (VS Code has a corresponding `Git: Fetch` command you can use the command palette).

---

> if I haven't yet checked a remote branch onto my local

I have never heard of this terminology. I assume you mean you haven't made a remote-tracking branch in your local clone.